# ipatool fails to build with bitcode (xcode 7.1.1)

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

using XCode 7.1.1 I try to export my project for ad-hoc deployment and get the generic error:

> An error occurred during export. The data couldn’t be read because it
>   isn’t in the correct format

Now, in the summary archive summary screen if i disable bitcode, all is well.
What can go wrong with bitcode?

In the logs all I find is this:

```
2015-11-30 09:35:08 +0000  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- cfpropertylist (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:15:in `<main>'
```

any tips?

Comment: mine fails too, thanks you save me tonnes of time searching

Comment: Same thing.  No idea.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem on XCode 10.1 after clicking *Distribute App* on the *Organizer*.

In my case it was because I invoked XCode from my terminal and `rvm` had configured a different ruby version. Running `rvm system` fixed it for me.